# I cannot access the default Apache webserver page, which is hosted in a VirtualBox VM, from my machine

Tags: apache, virtual-machine

My machine is a regular laptop with Windows 7. I have a Virtualbox VM running Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 and I have apache2 installed. When I try to access the default webserver page (10.0.2.15) from my machine, it cannot find the page. I have disabled my machine's firewall so that isn't causing the issue. The network for my VM is NAT, but I also tried the bridged adapter setting to no avail. Any suggestions would help.

Comment: http://superuser.com/

Comment: What is not helpful is people not using the right StackExchange network for their question and think that StackOverflow is meant for any kind of question. You could even go directly to http://askubuntu.com/ however given you want VBox and Ubuntu superuser is more indicated or even VBox directly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you ping the server? If so, try the netstat command in server terminal to determine if it listens to port 80. If you cannot ping it, check the network address, f.x with ifconfig

Comment: Request timeout when trying to ping the server from my machine. The VM can ping itself just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you can ping apache from the server, you probably have a problem with the network.

Try to add an host only interface. Then, in your VM, `sudo ifconfig`. Use the eth1's ip.